# 2D Platformer in Java. Loading level not working

Tags: java, 2d, game-physics

So, I made a platformer game. It uses multiple levels.

```
public void switchLevel() {
    clearLevel();
    cam.setX(0);
    try {
        BufferedImage currentLevel = loader.loadImage("/level" + String.valueOf(Game.LEVEL + 1) + ".png");
        loadImageLevel(currentLevel);
        System.out.println("LOADED LEVEL " + (Game.LEVEL+1));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("LEVEL " + String.valueOf(Game.LEVEL + 1) + " NOT FOUND!");
    }
    Game.LEVEL++;
}
```

This is my function for switching levels. Whenever it has to switch from level 3 to 4 it immediately loads another level. This happens only on level 4.

This is part of my console output

```
TEST><TRYING TO LOAD LEVEL3
512 512
LOADED LEVEL 3
FPS: 1676 TICKS: 60
FPS: 2089 TICKS: 60
FPS: 2160 TICKS: 60
FPS: 2273 TICKS: 60
FPS: 2323 TICKS: 60
FPS: 2318 TICKS: 60
FPS: 2326 TICKS: 60
<<MORE FPS LOGS>>
TEST><TRYING TO LOAD LEVEL4
512 512
LOADED LEVEL 4
TEST><TRYING TO LOAD LEVEL5
512 512
LOADED LEVEL 5
FPS: 1458 TICKS: 60
FPS: 1364 TICKS: 59
FPS: 1342 TICKS: 61
FPS: 1366 TICKS: 60
```

I can't see what is wrong with it.. 
Also sorry for my bad english

EDIT:
The method gets called when the player collides with a Flag object.

This is part of the Collision Method:

```
case Flag: {
                if (getBounds().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {
                    handler.switchLevel();
                }
                break;
            }
```

Comment: So the program is skipping level 4 and immediately going from 3 to 5? We probably need to see where `switchLevel()` gets called.

Comment: I think you want to `return` from the collision method when you collide with a flag just to stop all other collisions. Also, could there be two overlapping flags at the end of level 3? Or a flag at the beginning of level 4? You could put some print statements in the collision method to check when `switchLevel()` is being called.

Comment: Well, the `return` part made it work
Thank you very much